# Array access with char index in Java

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

While seeing the explanation for a Java programming exercise online, I came upon the following piece of code:

```
int[] count = new int[128];
int length = 0;
for(char c: s.toCharArray()){
    if(++count[c] == 2){
        length += 2;
        count[c] = 0;
    }
}
```

I understand what the code does but I don't know how it can access an array element using a char index (i.e.count[c], where c is a char). I thought indexes could only be integers?

Comment: every char is an integer (or can implicitly and silently converted to one without any loss of data), but not every integer is a char.

Comment: `int i = c; if (++count[i] == 2)` is what is happening, where one can have an IndexOutOfBoundsException for non-ASCII (`§ é € ½ ©`)

Comment: To the extent it is useful, `new int[Character.MAX_VALUE+1]` would cover all UTF-16 code units. It probably wouldn't be useful for Unicode codepoints that UTF-16 encodes in two code units , nor for [grapheme clusters](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries) (aka "user-percieved characters"). But is seems you expect only the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A char (16 bit) is an int (32 bit), not vice versa. This is an implicit casting, char to unsigned int in particular.
In this case, the index will probabily be the ASCII code representing this char (for ASCII characters).

Comment: Thanks!! Does this also happen with other types (e.g. strings) ?

Comment: No, basically because String is not a primitive type.  A string can contains more then one char and there is not implicit conversion. Maybe you can put an integer in a String and the make an explicit conversion to int, but is not a very good idea...

Answer (score 4):

The char is implicitly cast to an int. The index is still an int.

Answer (score 0):

So Basically Each Character is defined by Ascii value. So when you try to use char as int. It will use it as defined Ascii value.

That's why its working.